# upload file via ajax with jquery easy ui

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-easyui

I'm trying to give users the possibility to import data from a file that is located on their computer by using [jQuery EasyUI form widget](http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/form.php):

```
<form id="my_form" method="POST">
    <input type="file" name="my_file" id="my_file" />
</form>

var file_name = $('#my_file').val();

if(file_name)
{       
    $('#my_form').form('submit', {
        url: [url_to_call],
        onSubmit: function(param){
             param.file_path = file_name;
        }
    });
}
```

Then when the user browse on his/her computer for the file, I wanna send the path to a jQuery ajax query to perform some upload action. The problem I have is that `filename` returns something like this:

```
C:\fakepath\[name_of_file]
```

Because of the `fakepath` string, I am not getting the real path to where the file is located on the user's computer. Does anybody know how I can fix this issue please?

Thank you

Comment: You can't really upload a file with ajax, you have to either upload a formData object, or for non-supporting browsers use an iframe.

Comment: @adeneo Nope, I have implemented Ajax upload in one of my app which supported IE7+ upload of image. I show them image preview just after upload (without page-refresh).

Comment: why not use google ? for the ajax and file-upload fan´s this may be on of the most asked question arround

Comment: @KingAnirudhaIII - That's something completely different, that's the HTML5 file API that shows the image from the users computer, and noone said you had to reload the page, but you can't upload an image from a file input directly, you have to upload the formData object containing the image file or use an iframe to submit the form in browsers that don't support formData.

Answer (score 0):

Tried this plugin http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#getting-started

this plugin provide a method called AjaxSubmit() which work fine for upload the image. I have used it in 2011.

it's have some issue in IE (old version like 6,7). You need to write some hacks. on the backend Firefox and IE upload the correct file-stream format like `Data/Image` but in Chrome (Webkit) you will got Octet Stream. You need to parse the file format on server to check that file is not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what your `form()` function does, as no such method exists in jQuery, but the usual way of uploading a file to the server would be something like this :

```
$('#my_file').on('change', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url  : [url_to_call],
        data : new FormData($('#my_form').get(0)),
        processData: false,
        contenttype: false
    }).done(function(param) {
        param.file_path = file_name;
    });
});
```